# Why the most natural query(I.e. using INNER JOIN (instead of LEFT JOIN)) is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

This query takes too long.

```
explain analyze

select 

c.company_rec_id, 
c.the_company_code ,
c.company

from 
tlist t

-- it is questionable why this query become fast when using left join, the most natural query is inner join...
join mlist m using(mlist_rec_id)
join parcel_application ord_app using(parcel_application_rec_id)
join parcel ord using(parcel_rec_id)
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id
-- ...questionable

where 
(
    'cadmium' = ''

    or

    exists
    (
    select * 
        from mlist_detail md
        where 
            md.mlist_rec_id = m.mlist_rec_id        
            and exists
            (
                select *
                from mlist_detail_parameter mdp            
                join parameter p using(parameter_rec_id)
                where mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id = md.mlist_detail_rec_id            
                    and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))       
            )

    )
)
group by c.company_rec_id, 
    c.the_company_code, c.company
```

...here's the execution plan:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=3791153.43..3791156.38 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=222284.340..222284.357 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3791139.81 rows=1816 width=71) (actual time=421.412..222282.253 rows=715 loops=1)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..3790598.03 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=421.395..222273.876 rows=715 loops=1)"
"              Merge Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_rec_id)::text = (ord.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3790229.12 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=421.371..222264.556 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3789062.60 rows=1816 width=74) (actual time=421.346..222250.614 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using fki_parcel_application__parcel on parcel_application ord_app  (cost=0.00..508.50 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=0.019..6.952 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist__parcel_application on mlist m  (cost=0.00..1177.29 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=66.900..69.060 rows=0 loops=3218)"
"                                Index Cond: ((m.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"                                Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2)"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=3.49..5870.46 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=61.189..61.189 rows=0 loops=3631)"
"                                        Join Filter: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                        ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist_detail__mlist on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..24.31 rows=5 width=37) (actual time=0.014..0.023 rows=4 loops=3631)"
"                                              Index Cond: ((mlist_rec_id)::text = ($0)::text)"
"                                        ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.57 rows=676 width=37) (actual time=0.004..16.045 rows=1865 loops=13473)"
"                                              Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                              ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (actual time=0.001..5.935 rows=36353 loops=13473)"
"                                              ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.646..1.646 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                    ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.397..1.642 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                          Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                                SubPlan 2"
"                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1180.47..3241.32 rows=15198 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                        Hash Cond: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..1987.79 rows=17679 width=74) (never executed)"
"                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1172.02..1172.02 rows=676 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1165.26..1172.02 rows=676 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.57 rows=676 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                          Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                                          ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (never executed)"
"                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                                      Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                    ->  Index Scan using fki_tlist__mlist on tlist t  (cost=0.00..0.63 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=715)"
"                          Index Cond: ((t.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_parcel on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..338.49 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=0.008..3.312 rows=3146 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_company on company c  (cost=0.00..0.29 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=715)"
"              Index Cond: ((c.company_rec_id)::text = (ord.client_rec_id)::text)"
"Total runtime: 222284.584 ms"
```

When I convert it to left join.

```
explain analyze

select 

c.company_rec_id, 
c.the_company_code ,
c.company

from 
tlist t

-- it is questionable why this query become fast when using left join, the most natural query is inner join...
left join mlist m using(mlist_rec_id)
left join parcel_application ord_app using(parcel_application_rec_id)
left join parcel ord using(parcel_rec_id)
left join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id
-- ...questionable

where 
(
    'cadmium' = ''

    or

    exists
    (
        select * 
        from mlist_detail md
        where 
            md.mlist_rec_id = m.mlist_rec_id        
            and exists
            (
                select *
                from mlist_detail_parameter mdp            
                join parameter p using(parameter_rec_id)
                where mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id = md.mlist_detail_rec_id            
                    and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))            
            )

    )
)
group by c.company_rec_id, 
    c.the_company_code, c.company
```

...it become fast:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=4276494.40..4276497.35 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=71.299..71.309 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..4276480.78 rows=1816 width=71) (actual time=35.271..70.776 rows=715 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..4275939.00 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=35.260..66.157 rows=715 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..4275263.92 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=35.243..60.185 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.00..4274523.56 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=35.226..54.834 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                          Merge Cond: ((t.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"                          Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using fki_tlist__mlist on tlist t  (cost=0.00..710.72 rows=3631 width=37) (actual time=0.011..1.947 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using pk_mlist on mlist m  (cost=0.00..482.71 rows=3631 width=74) (actual time=0.008..1.829 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                          SubPlan 1"
"                            ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=3.49..5870.46 rows=5 width=0) (never executed)"
"                                  Join Filter: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist_detail__mlist on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..24.31 rows=5 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((mlist_rec_id)::text = ($0)::text)"
"                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.57 rows=676 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                        Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (never executed)"
"                                        ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                              ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                    Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                          SubPlan 2"
"                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=1180.47..3241.32 rows=15198 width=37) (actual time=16.478..34.359 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                  Hash Cond: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                  ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..1987.79 rows=17679 width=74) (actual time=0.004..3.013 rows=17679 loops=1)"
"                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1172.02..1172.02 rows=676 width=37) (actual time=16.461..16.461 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1165.26..1172.02 rows=676 width=37) (actual time=15.790..16.037 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.57 rows=676 width=37) (actual time=1.613..15.037 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                                    Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                                    ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (actual time=0.002..4.624 rows=37187 loops=1)"
"                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.593..1.593 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                          ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.311..1.588 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                    ->  Index Scan using pk_parcel_application on parcel_application ord_app  (cost=0.00..0.40 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=715)"
"                          Index Cond: ((m.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_parcel on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..0.36 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=715)"
"                    Index Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_rec_id)::text = (ord.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_company on company c  (cost=0.00..0.29 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=715)"
"              Index Cond: ((c.company_rec_id)::text = (ord.client_rec_id)::text)"
"Total runtime: 71.504 ms"
```

It works with its natural query (I.e. INNER JOIN) if I do this (note the superfluous EXISTS between mlist_detail_parameter and parameter table).

```
explain analyze
select 

c.company_rec_id, 
c.the_company_code ,
c.company

from 
tlist t

join mlist m using(mlist_rec_id)
join parcel_application ord_app using(parcel_application_rec_id)
join parcel ord using(parcel_rec_id)
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id

where 
(
    'cadmium' = ''

    or

    exists
    (
        select * 
        from mlist_detail md
        where 
            md.mlist_rec_id = m.mlist_rec_id        
            and exists
            (
                select * from mlist_detail_parameter mdp
                where mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id = md.mlist_detail_rec_id
                    -- Notice that there is no joining of parameter TO mlist_detail_parameter; We use EXISTS instead, which looks very superfluous
                    and exists
                    (
                        select * from parameter p
                        where parameter_rec_id = mdp.parameter_rec_id
                        and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))
                    )

            )

    )
)

group by c.company_rec_id, 
    c.the_company_code, c.company
```

..., it works:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=76424.17..76427.12 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=398.906..398.932 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..76410.55 rows=1816 width=71) (actual time=52.529..398.171 rows=715 loops=1)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..75868.77 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=45.106..385.128 rows=715 loops=1)"
"              Merge Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_rec_id)::text = (ord.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..75499.86 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=41.745..374.833 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..74333.34 rows=1816 width=74) (actual time=31.483..302.607 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using fki_parcel_application__parcel on parcel_application ord_app  (cost=0.00..508.50 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=2.459..5.797 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist__parcel_application on mlist m  (cost=0.00..22.93 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.089..0.092 rows=0 loops=3218)"
"                                Index Cond: ((m.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"                                Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 3 or hashed SubPlan 6)"
"                                SubPlan 3"
"                                  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..112.64 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.071..0.071 rows=0 loops=3631)"
"                                        ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist_detail__mlist on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..24.31 rows=5 width=37) (actual time=0.019..0.023 rows=4 loops=3631)"
"                                              Index Cond: ((mlist_rec_id)::text = ($0)::text)"
"                                        ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist_detail_parameter__mlist_detail on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..19.63 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=13473)"
"                                              Index Cond: ((mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                              Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2)"
"                                              SubPlan 1"
"                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.67 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)"
"                                                      Filter: (((parameter_rec_id)::text = ($1)::text) AND (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text)))"
"                                              SubPlan 2"
"                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.475..1.774 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                      Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                                SubPlan 6"
"                                  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..128665.02 rows=15198 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..1987.79 rows=17679 width=74) (never executed)"
"                                        ->  Index Scan using fki_mlist_detail_parameter__mlist_detail on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..7.83 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                              Index Cond: ((mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                              Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 4 or hashed SubPlan 5)"
"                                              SubPlan 4"
"                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.67 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)"
"                                                      Filter: (((parameter_rec_id)::text = ($1)::text) AND (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text)))"
"                                              SubPlan 5"
"                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (never executed)"
"                                                      Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                    ->  Index Scan using fki_tlist__mlist on tlist t  (cost=0.00..0.63 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=1 loops=715)"
"                          Index Cond: ((t.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_parcel on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..338.49 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=3.277..5.920 rows=3146 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_company on company c  (cost=0.00..0.29 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=715)"
"              Index Cond: ((c.company_rec_id)::text = (ord.client_rec_id)::text)"
"Total runtime: 399.649 ms"
```

Even though that is fast, I think it is not natural to use superfluous EXISTS.

```
and exists
(
    select * from mlist_detail_parameter mdp
    where mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id = md.mlist_detail_rec_id

    -- Notice that there is no joining of parameter to mlist_detail_parameter, we use EXISTS instead
    and exists -- SUPERFLUOUS
    (
        select * from parameter p
        where parameter_rec_id = mdp.parameter_rec_id
        and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))
    )

)
```

..., when join will do:

```
and exists
(
   select *
    from mlist_detail_parameter mdp            
    join parameter p using(parameter_rec_id)
    where mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id = md.mlist_detail_rec_id          
    and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))
)
```

My question is why the most natural query(I.e. using INNER JOIN (instead of LEFT JOIN)) is very slow. I can opt to use the query without LEFT JOINs but I must use superfluous EXISTS on mlist_detail_parameter and parameter tables, instead of using straight joining.

The sweetest performance spot I found is to just use LEFT JOINs, but I think applying LEFT JOINs **blindly** could lead me to Cargo Cult Programming

**[EDIT: 2010-07-06]**

Darn, I'm a fan of IN query now, I converted the EXISTS query to IN query, it is staggering fast now.

This query.

```
explain analyze

select 

c.company_rec_id, 
c.the_company_code ,
c.company

from 
tlist t

-- it is questionable why this query become fast when using left join, the most natural query is inner join...
join mlist m using(mlist_rec_id)
join parcel_application ord_app using(parcel_application_rec_id)
join parcel ord using(parcel_rec_id)
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id
-- ...questionable

where 
(
    'cadmium' = ''

    or

    mlist_rec_id in 
    (
        select mlist_rec_id
        from mlist_detail md
        where 
            mlist_detail_rec_id in             
            (
                select mlist_detail_rec_id
                from mlist_detail_parameter mdp            
                join parameter p using(parameter_rec_id)
                where to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))       
            )

    )
)
group by c.company_rec_id, 
    c.the_company_code, c.company
```

...has this execution plan(0.037 second):

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=4045.22..4048.17 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=37.117..37.128 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3734.44..4031.60 rows=1816 width=71) (actual time=33.610..36.650 rows=715 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: ((ord.client_rec_id)::text = (c.company_rec_id)::text)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=3718.80..3990.99 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=33.448..36.150 rows=715 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_rec_id)::text = (ord.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3601.34..3844.02 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=32.096..34.360 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((m.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=3438.94..3652.11 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=30.578..32.370 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((t.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on tlist t  (cost=3278.24..3459.63 rows=1816 width=37) (actual time=28.930..30.219 rows=715 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (hashed SubPlan 1)"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1179.63..3240.24 rows=15201 width=37) (actual time=17.259..27.282 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                        Hash Cond: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..1987.79 rows=17679 width=74) (actual time=0.002..4.160 rows=17679 loops=1)"
"                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1171.48..1171.48 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=17.236..17.236 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1164.96..1171.48 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=16.290..16.692 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.33 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=0.868..15.420 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                                          Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                                          ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (actual time=0.002..5.397 rows=37187 loops=1)"
"                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.850..0.850 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.719..0.848 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                      Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=115.31..115.31 rows=3631 width=74) (actual time=1.632..1.632 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on mlist m  (cost=0.00..115.31 rows=3631 width=74) (actual time=0.002..0.569 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=122.18..122.18 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=1.507..1.507 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application ord_app  (cost=0.00..122.18 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=0.002..0.531 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=78.87..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=1.345..1.345 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=0.002..0.469 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=11.95..11.95 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=0.155..0.155 rows=295 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..11.95 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=0.003..0.063 rows=295 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 37.240 ms"
```

Some thoughts. I think, more than anything else, Postgresql just did a bad optimization on EXISTS clause, I don't expect that EXISTS clause to be very inherently slower than IN. In fact, I remember I optimized a non-peformant query before(I think that was 8.3 or 8.2) by converting the IN clauses to EXISTS clauses

Comment: the choice of LEFT JOIN versus INNER JOIN is not about performance; it is how the domain is modelled.

Comment: Meta-comment: is there a way to make this easier to read? (He's trying, I know.)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: +1 to you; "how the domain is modelled".  I concur, that's why I still want to use INNER JOIN, I'm joining tables from child to parent.  That's the model of my data or query, i.e. joining from child to parent, that's why I want to use INNER JOIN.  I don't want to use LEFT JOIN just because it fast.  Though in this query I can supposed that LEFT JOIN can be safely use, there's always a matching parent for a child

Comment: Michael, I don't understand the 'joining from child to parent' comment. (I've never understood the JOINs beyond "inner join forms Cartesian product, left looks up data in the right for all rows in the left, right looks up data in the left for all rows in the right". Parent-Child relationships in this eludes me. :)

So, let's try this: are you trying to make a Cartesian product among the seven tables? (It even sounds expensive when stated like this. :) Or are you trying to find information six relationships away from your first table?

Comment: @sarnold: it's not cartesianed table.  re: parent to child, like detail to header, example:  Invoice(parent), InvoiceDetail(child).  Basically I'm joing the tables from child to parent, from InvoiceDetail to its parent table(Invoice)

Comment: re: "Or are you trying to find information six relationships away from your first table?"  Indeed, I can't help it, it's a very normalized database :-)

Comment: Michael, based on your new comments, I'm guessing that the left join is the more 'natural' join to use for your problem then. :) (Congrats on the good normalization. :)

Comment: What version do you use? Did you do an ANALYZE? And what about postgresql.conf? The current subplan 1 us just dead wrong, it has some nested loops you have to get rid of.

Comment: 8.4. I used EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I adjusted the postgresql.conf, I bumped it up a little (aware of Postgresql's conservative reserved memory settings), I forgot the exact amount of memory I reserved. I will post it here tomorrow when I go to office, I'm at home now.  The results in my question are from after I perform VACUUM

Comment: And did you run ANALYZE after the VACUUM? EXPLAIN ANALYZE is something else, it is NOT an ANALYZE, it does not change anything in the statistics and therfor doesn't give the queryplanner information about your data.

Comment: Moved from answer to comments.

Consider using integer type ids instead of string types as it has a penalty. It doesn't explain the difference in query time between the inner join and left outer join, but may reduce the query time overall quite dramatically. For some reason ids are casted to text.

I know this isn't a silver bullet and there are of course lots of parameters to consider. We have a data supplier that uses string keys and we use an internal integer keys instead of the supplied one and it is so much faster. The largest table contain about 500 million rows, so it isn't humoungous.

Comment: @Frank: hmm.. I didn't know that there's a standalone ANALYZE command.  Regarding EXPLAIN ANALYZE, yeah I know it does not change statistics; it only shows that when the query is executed, it shows how it executed it.  Rest assured, I perform VACUUM before I execute the EXPLAIN ANALYZE and posted the results here.  Tomorrow I'll check and try that ANALYZE, then I'll re-post here the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: Not an answer, but some thoughts:  (1) Why is "'cadmium' = ''" in there?  That will never be true.  (2) Try SELECT 1 instead of SELECT * for your sub-queries and end each sub-query with LIMIT 1--as written it appears that you don't care what the results are, just that you get at least one match.  (3)  See if you can "roll-up" some of the sub-queries into joins.  While you may have to add a DISTINCT in those cases, it should make the intent clearer.  (4)  If you really need to use the sub-queries here, use the WHERE x IN (select x from ...) method as it makes the intent much clearer.

Comment: @Matthew: re: 1) Both of literal 'cadmium' is *:_chemical_parameter* from Npgsql's Parameter.AddWithValue, I substitute a value in pgadmin so I can measure actual time. 2) Regarding SELECT 1 vs SELECT * inside EXISTS check, kindly read this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/05/why-is-exists-select-1-cargo-cult.html 3) I already tried rolling up the subqueries into joins, in fact that's the original query, check my first query above, then compare it to the third query(the one with superfluous EXISTS subquery for chemical parameter), EXISTS is faster than its JOIN counterpart

Comment: If the comment here works, I will suggest to the stacker to move his comment to answer so I can properly accept it as an answer

Comment: What are your join_collapse_limit and from_collapse_limit set to? (You can find out by running queries like "SHOW join_collapse_limit;")

Comment: @Matthew: Put your IN suggestion to answer, though you suggest it for readability purposes, that suggestion fits the bill on my query optimization, I will accept it as an answer.  If you can extrapolate why it is faster, the better

Comment: Wow... I'm going to have to take a class on databases now... Seems like it might be interesting :D

Comment: @Stephen: SHOW join_collapse_limit --> 8

Comment: @Michael (RE: literal 'cadmium' = ''): I suspected as such.  FYI, you might get different results because the planner will always evaluate the expression <literal1> = <literal2> as FALSE and look no further. If it was a prepared statement, then it would have to check the statistics and plan against the possibility that the parameter is the empty string (which would be TRUE, so a slightly different result).  Not quite comparing apples and oranges, but maybe tangerines and oranges... :)

Comment: @Matthew Wood: re: prepared statement, I think so too; with literal values in conditions, the planner cannot bring prepared statement into action. Anyway, in my actual code, I used Parameter.AddWithValue (nary an iota of concatenated query) and I passed 'cadmium' to it, yet the query execute in the same speed(i.e. slow). Guess I have to wait for DO command, so in the future I won't need to put 'literal' = '' in the question I will post here :-)  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html

Comment: @Michael take a look at the `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(as directed, I'm putting part of my comment in an answer as it solved the problem)

Convert the EXISTS expressions into IN expressions.

This works better in this instance because the query will now be effectively evaluated from the "inside out" starting with the query that contains your most limiting factor: the full text search lookup.  That query is going to return a small set of rows that can be looked up directly against the primary key of the outer query (WHERE x in (SELECT X...)) as opposed to calling the "inner" query once per value of the outer query (or for all values in your original case, if I am reading it correctly).  The EXISTS method here results in Nested Loops (one evaluation of one query for each value in another) vs the IN method using Hash Joins (a much more efficient execution method in many, if not most, cases.

Notice that with the EXISTS method, there are four Nested Loops that execute with each running at least 3,000 times.  That cost adds up.  While it's not a direct comparison, you can treat Nested Loops like you would FOR loops in application code:  each time you invoke an inner loop, your big-O estimate goes up an order of magnitude: O(n) to O(n^2) to O(n^3), etc.

Hash Join is more like a map, where two arrays are stepped through at the same time and an operation is performed on both.  This is roughly linear (O(n)).  Think of these being nested as additive so it would go O(n) to O(2n) to O(3n), etc.

*Yeah, yeah, I know it's not quite the same thing, but the point is that having multiple nested loops usually indicates a slow query plan and comparing the two big-O style makes it easier to recognize, I believe.*

Nested Loops and EXISTS are not evil, per se, but for most cases where there is a base filter condition that ultimately effects everything (for example, the full text search in the question), an IN expression (or, in *some* cases, a proper JOIN) yields a much more efficient plan.

Answer (score 4):

Is your query essentially the following (this is hard to ask as a comment):

```
select 

c.company_rec_id, 
c.the_company_code,
c.company

from 

company c 

where

exists (
    select *
    from parameter p
    join mlist_detail_parameter mdp on mdp.parameter_rec_id = p.parameter_rec_id
    join mlist_detail md            on md.mlist_detail_rec_id = mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id
    join mlist m                    on m.mlist_rec_id = md.mlist_rec_id

    join parcel_application ord_app on ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id = m.parcel_application_rec_id
    join parcel ord                 on ord.parcel_rec_id = ord_app.parcel_rec_id

    join tlist t                    on t.mlist_rec_id = m.mlist_rec_id

    where
        ord.client_rec_id = c.company_rec_id
    and to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words('cadmium'))
)
```

**[EDIT: 2010-07-06, added by Michael Buen]**

```
"Hash Join  (cost=2152.94..2172.52 rows=232 width=71) (actual time=71.106..71.207 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((c.company_rec_id)::text = (ord.client_rec_id)::text)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..11.95 rows=295 width=71) (actual time=0.004..0.030 rows=295 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=2150.04..2150.04 rows=232 width=37) (actual time=71.077..71.077 rows=84 loops=1)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2147.72..2150.04 rows=232 width=37) (actual time=71.033..71.040 rows=84 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1783.22..2146.09 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=51.029..70.187 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1783.22..1938.61 rows=652 width=111) (actual time=51.014..55.913 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_rec_id)::text = (ord.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=1665.76..1810.55 rows=652 width=111) (actual time=48.360..52.004 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: ((ord_app.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (m.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application ord_app  (cost=0.00..122.18 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=0.003..1.485 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=1657.61..1657.61 rows=652 width=111) (actual time=48.331..48.331 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=164.19..1657.61 rows=652 width=111) (actual time=4.755..46.122 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: ((md.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.49..1485.51 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=1.638..40.974 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.49..1163.33 rows=652 width=37) (actual time=1.590..18.090 rows=1918 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: ((mdp.parameter_rec_id)::text = (p.parameter_rec_id)::text)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on mlist_detail_parameter mdp  (cost=0.00..1013.87 rows=37187 width=74) (actual time=0.003..5.499 rows=37187 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=3.48..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.568..1.568 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on parameter p  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=1.324..1.564 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (to_tsvector(regexp_replace((parameter)::text, '[\\(\\)\\!\\.\\/,\\-\\?]+'::text, ' '::text, 'g'::text)) @@ plainto_tsquery('cadmium'::text))"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using pk_mlist_detail on mlist_detail md  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1918)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((md.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text = (mdp.mlist_detail_rec_id)::text)"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=115.31..115.31 rows=3631 width=74) (actual time=3.096..3.096 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on mlist m  (cost=0.00..115.31 rows=3631 width=74) (actual time=0.003..0.994 rows=3631 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=78.87..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=2.640..2.640 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=0.004..0.876 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using fki_tlist__mlist on tlist t  (cost=0.00..0.31 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1918)"
"                          Index Cond: ((t.mlist_rec_id)::text = (m.mlist_rec_id)::text)"
"Total runtime: 71.373 ms"
```

Comment: hmm.. your answer is also fast (between 0.06 to 0.08 second), but not as fast as IN version (0.03 to 0.05 second). +1 nonetheless, your answer works.  Your answer is semantically the same with my query here.  Eventhough, I cannot use your query on my actual code, I refactor my original query so it can be used on two(or more) modules, I need the ord_app on outside of subquery, I have some modules that do some sort of GROUP_CONCAT on ord_app.  I wish I could +2 you for taking time to deduce the intent of my code, and writing an actual query for that :-)

Comment: @Michael, I'd be interested in the explain analyze of this query - can you edit this answer to include it?