# SQL select IN (select) process too long why?

Tags: sql

Lets say TABLE1 has 1 million entrys in it.

Table2 has 50k entries in it.

```
SELECT stringVal 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE idTable2=5
```

Result of select:

```
5
4
```

That select takes `0.02s` to process
But when i use it within IN it takes up to `20.20s`

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE stringVal IN (
   SELECT stringVal FROM TABLE2 where idTable2=5);
```

If i would use it like this it would process in 0.02s

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE stringVal IN (5,4);
```

Can anyone explain me how things work here ?

Comment: Which RBDMS? Try MySQL's explain/SQL Server's Execution plan/equivalent for yours to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your RDBMS is doing a poor job of executing your query, other RDBMS(e.g. SQL Server) can see that if a subquery is not correlated with an outer query it will internally *materialize* the result and would not execute the subquery repeatedly. e.g.

```
select *
    , (select count(*) from tbl) -- an smart RDBMS won't execute this repeatedly
from tbl
```

A good RDBMS would not execute the counting repeatedly, since it is an independent query(not correlated to the outside query)

Try all of the options, there are just few of them anyway

1st, try EXISTS. Your RDBMS's EXISTS ***might*** be faster than its IN.  I encountered IN is faster than EXISTS though, example: [Why the most natural query(I.e. using INNER JOIN (instead of LEFT JOIN)) is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177038/why-the-most-natural-queryi-e-using-inner-join-instead-of-left-join-is-very)  Same observation by Quassnoi (IN is faster than EXISTS): http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
   -- stringVal IN 
   EXISTS(
       SELECT * -- please, don't bikeshed ;-)
       FROM TABLE2            
       where 
             table1.stringVal = table2.stringVal -- simulated IN
             and table2.idTable2 = 5);
```

2nd, try INNER JOIN, use this if there's no duplicate, or use DISTINCT to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT stringVal -- remove duplicates
       FROM TABLE2            
       where table2.idTable2 = 5 ) as x
ON X.stringVal = table1.stringVal
```

3rd, try to materialize the rows yourself. I encountered same problem with SQL Server, querying the materialized rows is faster than querying the result of another query.

Check the example of materializing the query result to table, then using IN on result. I see that it is faster than using IN on another query approach, you can just read the bottom part of the post: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/recursive-cte-is-evil-and-cursor-is.html

Example:

```
SELECT distinct stringVal -- remove duplicates
into anotherTable
FROM TABLE2            
where idTable2 = 5;

SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 where stringVal in (select stringVal from anotherTable);
```

The above is working on Sql Server and Postgresql, on other RDBMS it might be like this:

```
create table anotherTable as
SELECT distinct stringVal -- remove duplicates
FROM TABLE2            
where table2.idTable2 = 5;


select count(*)
from table1 where stringVal in (select stringVal from anotherTable)
```

Comment: 2nd example of yours worked pretty well about 0.2s to process. Thx for those examples learning every day new things :)

Answer (score 1):

While I love subqueries, they are immensely powerful, their also quite slow, since the query has to be completely evaluated at each iteration, ouch! (depending on implementation)

This is why they are mine/our last resort.

Some SQL implementations are quite good and will cache the subquery though Im not quite sure how safe that would be, but still you have to traverse this entire structure and if the structure isn't properly optmize it would take quadratic even cubic time if you nest enough of them ...

```
SELECT stringVal 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE idTable2=5
```

This is linear time O(n), it can be even be constant O(1) if the sql database stores statistical information, but we will assume it doesn't as such it will search every row and return all those that match the where clause.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE stringVal IN (
   SELECT stringVal FROM TABLE2 where idTable2=5);
```

Assuming the subquery isn't cache then it is being evaluated at each row, and if you have a lof them thats a lot evaluations, many many wasted repeated calculations, and even if its cache the structure may not be optimal for search, not to mention you are also comparing strings, on a list of strings.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TABLE1  
WHERE stringVal IN (5,4);
```

The subquery is still being evaluated but its a constant expression theres basically no overhead at all, it doesn't need to do any IO or deal with locks or anythig :)

Comment: that's what i was afraid of, that at each iteration it would need to re do the select because it didn't cache. 
That might be the problem here.

Comment: yeah its dependent on the implementation some cache it, others don't, caching is quite dangerous, cause if the table is updated then you can return bad data you could have a lock but this really complicates things.

Comment: Im always fascinated by database design, its actually quite hard on par with developing a compiler or building a kernel ... :) good post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE1 where EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 where idTable2=5 and stringVal = TABLE1.stringVal  );
```

An you should create indexes for stringVal both TABLE1 and TABLE2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple join that will give you the same kind of result that you were looking for.  This can be applied in many different situations and this will avoid having to query against another table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.'COLUMN' = TABLE2.'COLUMN' AND TABLE2.IDTABLE2=5 
WHERE 'WHATEVER YOU WANT'
```

Replace 'COLUMN' with a column that is referenced in both tables, normally an ID or primary key.